# Change the yum repo of the installed package

Tags: centos, yum

I have an rpm package installed with yum from a community repository server and need to switch to another repository server.
yum does not allow having shared names of packages between different repositories. How can I switch do another repository and upgrade installed package?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum  --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='newrepo' updateinfo
sudo yum  --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='newrepo' install packageName-newerVersion
sudo systemctl daemon-reexec (this may not be needed on centos 8)
sudo systemctl restart packageName
```